# Migrating MongoDB Atlas to XConnect [upgrading sitecore 8.2 to sitecore 9.3]

Tags: xconnect, upgrade, mongodb

Currently I am working in Sitecore upgrade 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3 also upgrading Sitecore 8.2 analytics code to Xconnect. Now I have some doubts in xDB data migration.

We already have our xDB setup on Mongo 3.6 Atlas PAAS for Sitecore 8.2. I would like to understand how to migrate xDB data which is available in MongoDB atlas 3.6 to Mongo 4.0.5 mongo atlas which we are going to use for Sitecore 9.3. Is it possible to use xDB migration tool ?

Could someone please suggest how to migrate xDB data from mongo atlas 3.6 to mongo atlas 4.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

To migrate data to sitecore 9.3 you can use `xDB Data Migration Tool 4.0` which can be downloaded from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_xDB_Data_Migration_Tool/4x/xDB_Data_Migration_Tool_400.aspx, you will also find the [installation guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/41191BDAA34D45E88AD09E79787248E1.ashx?date=20200401T113136) listed there. You would need to install these features in this order:

- Data Exchange Framework 4.0
- xDB Data Migration Tool for Data Exchange Framework 4.0
- The verification database dacpac file to deployed to SQL Server, if you want to capture the records that are being migrated